# Grep/Sed between two tags with multiline

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have many files from which I need to get information.

Example of my files:

first file content:

`"test This info i need grep</singleline>"`

and

second file content (with two lines):

```
"test This info=
 i need grep too</singleline>"
```

in results I need grep this text: from first file - "This info i need grep" and from second file - "This info= i need grep too"

In first file I use:

```
grep -o 'test .*</singleline>' * | sed -e 's/test \(.*\)<\/singleline>/\1/'
```

and successfully get "This info i need grep" but I can not get the information from the second file by using the same command.

Please help rewrite the command or write what the other.

Comment: That's because grep is line matching you'd have to use the -n option and awk to get the infor you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use `pcregrep`, which can match multiline regexes:

```
pcregrep -Mo 'test \K((?s).)*?(?=</singleline>)' filename
```

The tricks are:

- `-M` allows `pcregrep` to match on more than one line,
- `-o` makes it print only the match,
- `\K` throws away the part of the match that comes before it,
- `(?=</singleline>)` is a lookahead term that matches an empty string if (and only if) it is followed by `</singleline>`, and
- `((?s).)*?` to match any characters non-greedily, which is to say that if you have several occurrences of `</singleline>` in the file, it will match until the closest rather than the furthest. If this is not desired, remove the `?`. `(?s)` enables the `s` option locally for the term to make `.` match newlines in it; it wouldn't do that by default.

Thanks to @CasimiretHippolyte for pointing out the `((?s).)` alternative to `(.|\n)`.

Comment: For OP: If you don't have `pcregrep` you can get it by `sudo apt-get install pcregrep`. For @wintermute, good answer and explanation.

Comment: You should avoid this ugly (and inefficient) construction `(.|\n)*?` that is more designed for posix engines (except the non-greedy quantifier). You can for example replace it with `([^<]*)` or `((?s).*?)` (if you want to allow other angle brackets).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks, that's a good idea. I put in `((?s).)`; I don't think it'd be good to exclude `<`. Where there's one xml-ish tag, there might be others.

Comment: it is a good alternative! Tell me please, can a program to display the search results in one line? For example, programm find: This info=
 i need grep too   , and i need "This info= i need grep too" (in one line)

Comment: `pcregrep` itself won't do that, but you can pipe the output through `tr -d '\n'` or so.

Comment: @Serg: an other way consists to use the hold buffer of sed. Take a look here to see sed capabilities: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-55

Comment: `sed '1h;1!H;$!d;x;s/\n//g'` is a way that works with all seds I'm aware of (BSD sed, as found on *BSD and MacOS X is unwieldy with many other approaches to multi-line sed). Another way is to do the whole thing in slurp-mode Perl: `perl -0777 -nE '($_)=m/test \K(((?s).)*?)(?=<\/singleline>)/; s/\n//g; say' filename` -- the `$_=

Comment: Mind you, the slurp-mode Perl (as written) will only isolate the first match. I don't know what you want to happen if there are two possible matches in the file.

Answer (score 6):

Or, if you insist to use `grep`, you can:

```
grep -Pzo 'test(\n|.)*(?=</singleline>)' test.txt
```

To understand the meaning of each flag, use `grep --help`:

- `-P`, --perl-regexp

  PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
- `-o`, --only-matching

  show only the part of a line matching PATTERN
- `-z`, --null-data

  a data line ends in 0 byte, not newline

Comment: Neat trick; to clarify: by specifying NUL as the "line" separator with `-z`, you effectively read the _entire_ input _at once_, which then allows you to match _across_ lines.
I suggest using a non-greedy quantifier (`*?` instead of `*`), as in @Wintermute's answer.

Comment: The issue is that if case of redirection of matching to a file `grep -Pzo` writes byte with value `0` at the end of file. Then this `0-byte` causes `diff` to interpret text file as binary file. How to prevent writing `0-byte` at the end of the file to which we redirect?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're parsing quoted-printable encoded text, where a "soft" line break (one that is an artifact from fixed-line-width formatting) is indicated with a line-terminating `=` (directly before the `\n`).

Since in a *later* comment you also expressed the desire to print each match as a single line, I suggest the following 2-pass appraoch:

- use `awk` to remove the soft line breaks
- then use `grep` on the result

```sh
awk '/=$/ { printf "%s", substr($0, 1, length($0)-2); next } 1' file |
  grep -Po 'test .*?(?=</singleline>)'
```

<sup>Tip of the hat to [Wintermute's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30140360/45375) for the non-greedy quantifier, `*?`, and both Wintermute's and [Maroun Maroun's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30140425/45375) for the positive look-ahead assertion, `(?=...)`.</sup>

Not that the `awk` command *removes* the line-ending `=` (along with the newline); replace the `substr` call with just `$0` to retain it.

Since strings of interest are first converted back their original single-line representations:

- The matches are printed in their original form.
- You can use regular (GNU) `grep` with line-by-line matching; contrast this with

  - needing to read the entire file *at once*, as in [Maroun Maroun's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30140425/45375).
    <sup>Note that, as of this writing, `*` must be replaced with `*?` in his answer to work correctly work in files with multiple matches.</sup>
  - needing to install another utility, `pcregrep`, as in [Wintermute's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30140360/45375).
  - additionally, the matches would have to be cleaned up to be single-line (something you didn't originally state as a requirement).